# How To Get This To Save To Where My App Is Located

Tags: swift, macos

Save data to file

```
let fileName = "Test"
let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")

let writeString = "Write this text to the fileURL as text in iOS using Swift"
do {
    // Write to the file
    try writeString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

var readString = "" // Used to store the file contents
do {
    // Read the file contents
    readString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
print("File Text: \(readString)")
```

How can I get this to save the Test.txt file to save where my App directory is. I don't know where this is saving the Text File to.

Comment: Maybe you want the current working directory? https://iswift.org/cookbook/get-current-directory-path

Comment: You are printing the URL, so what do you mean you don't know where your code is saving the `String` to?

Comment: What platform are you even targeting? In iOS you only have access to your application's directory due to app sandboxing (same actually for sandboxed macOS apps).

Comment: You are discouraged from doing that. There are default directories for user data for example `Application Support`

Comment: You already asked two questions about appending text to a file and there were suitable answers.

Comment: Didn't work, the code doesn't append it overwrites the text already in the file. I need it to add text to new line.